# What's the difference between a static library built for osx and for the ios-simulator

Tags: ios, macos, clang

If I take the same source code and use clang to compile it into a static library, once for osx and once for the ios simulator, both with arch x86_64, what are the technical differences between the two resulting static libs?

This is theoretical, I'm interested in better understanding the structure of the underlying lib. For instance if I use different architectures (armv7 vs x86_64) the difference is quite clear to me. But when the architecture is the same the difference is not clear.

Comment: Good question, I'm not sure, but I guess it will be nearly the same,
except that in case of ios-simualtor, compiler will use DEFINES to add/exclude some APIs which available on iOS/OSX  operation systems.

Comment: If you try to use a static lib built for osx when building for the ios simulator in Xcode you get the message "building for iOS simulator, but linking in object file built for OSX". So Xcode can tell them apart, I wonder how it does that

Comment: Also, @IAmDav, would that result in a difference in the lib itself, or only in the applications that embed the lib and include/import the headers - which might ultimately import platform headers where the defines come into effect

Comment: I guess in static library compiler/linker sets the target architetecture to iOS Simulator/OSX, that why Xcode "understands" the type of lib.

Comment: Actually defines comes into effect also during static lib compilation/linkage.
I guess lib itself will be different for simualator/osx